# Sample HTML code for a complex form control (see mockup)

Tags: html, forms, jquery-ui, user-interface

I have tried searching for this but I do not know the name of the control or UI so I am not having any luck.  I'd like to know if there is a name for this UI and if you know of a good link to sample html that would be ideal.

It will be used inside of a jQuery UI dialog box as well as on a standard page within a web app.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a two-sided multi-select list...

The [jQuery two-sided multi-select list](http://www.jsplugins.com/Scripts/Plugins/View/Jquery-Two-Sided-Multi-Selector/) converts a normal drop down list into the mock-up you've posted and automatically moves selected items over to the right-hand list as well as adding buttons for movement (plus you can double-click items to move them back and forth).